# Reading data from Excel using JDBC ODBC

Tags: excel, jdbc, odbc

Can some one please explain how to read data from excel sheet using JDBC ODBC with out using DSN.

Answer (score 0):

```java
final static String DRIVER_NAME = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=%s;DriverID=22;READONLY=false";

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\z671866\\Desktop\\TAS_VAS\\TOS_ERROR_05092014.xlsx");      
    Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(
            DATABASE_URL, file.getAbsolutePath()));

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SN,IR FROM [Sheet1$]");
    while( rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString("SN"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("IR"));
    }

}
```

Comment: If you edit your own answer, please don't ruin the code formatting. I have rolled back your previous edit.

Answer (score 0):

**use this Code for to Persian and chinese text:**

```
String new_Str = new String(excelfield.getBytes(1), "Cp1256"); //....to Persian text

String new_Str = new String(excelfield.getBytes(1), "UTF-8"); //....to Chinese text
```

**OR**

```
String new_Str = new String(your_str.getBytes(), "Cp1256");

String new_Str = new String(your_str.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```